# How to update value of a model in views.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Goodmorning Guys,

I'm new in django and I want to ask you the following question.

I have in models.py two class:

```
class Single_Income(models.Model):

  income_label = models.CharField(max_length=100, editable=True)

  income_jan = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
  income_feb= MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)



class Total_Income(models.Model):

  total_jan = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
  total_feb= MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
```

In views I have the following code:

```
def ricavi_dalle_vendite(request):
    items = Single_Income.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = SingleIncomeModelForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             print("Il form è valido")
             new_input = form.save()

    else :
        form = SingleIncomeModelForm()

    context= {
        "form": form,
        'items': items,
            }
    return render(request, "app/income.html", context)
```

So completing the form in the web_application (url "app/income.html") it's possible to fill the Single_Income. Now I want to fill automatically the Total_Income model (after the saving of Single_Income model data) in this way:

Single_Income:

---

|____Jan____|___Fab_____|

|____100___|_____100____|

|____100____|____100____|

Total_Income:

---

|____200____|____200____|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of your `Total_Income` by calling `Total_Income`. As an example:

```py
from . models import Total_Income, Single_Income
from django.db.models import Sum

def ricavi_dalle_vendite(request):
    items = Single_Income.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = SingleIncomeModelForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             print("Il form è valido")
             new_input = form.save()

             # get sums of income_jan and income_feb for all records in Single_Income
             data_jan = Single_Income.objects.aggregate(Sum('income_jan'))
             data_feb = Single_Income.objects.aggregate(Sum('income_feb'))
             jan = data_jan['income_jan__sum']
             feb = data_jan['income_feb__sum']

             # or, sum the incomes from the form
             data_jan = new_input.aggregate(Sum('income_jan'))
             data_feb = new_input.aggregate(Sum('income_feb'))
             jan = data_jan['income_jan__sum']
             feb = data_jan['income_feb__sum'] 

             # create a Total_Income instance
             total_income = Total_Income(total_jan=jan, total_feb=feb)
             # you must save the instance after creating it if you want it to persist
             total_income.save() 

             context= {
               "form": form,
               'items': items,
               'total_income': total_income
             }

    return render(request, "app/income.html", context)
```

Now you can access `total_income` in your template much like you were accessing `items`.

Comment: thanks for your answer @anowlinorbit. the problem is that my Single_Income.objects.value are given from the user in a form model. I don't know their value. The second problem is that my Total Income must be the sum of Single_Income montly intance.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you want to input the single income values in the form, and then show a total income without POSTing a request?  Have I understood you correctly? If this is the case, then you will have to use some Javascript. It should be quite straightforward.  You can add the JS to your template. Then, when you handle the incoming POST request with the single income values, you can calculate the total income values and create a Total_Income instance.

Comment: I think I know what you're asking. I misread something you wrote. Give me a few minutes and I'll post something in the answer I gave.

Comment: ohhh thanks you. Please explain me patiently becouse I'm not good at with java :)

Comment: I've updated the python code. This will calculate the totals of income_jan, income_feb. I've shown two options, one which calculates the total for all Single_Income data, and the other which only calculates the totals from the data on the form. Keep in mind, you must POST the request to get this information from Django. If you want to do it dynamically in the browser, and without sending the data to Django, you'll need Javascript.

Comment: thanks you so much @anowlinorbit. I have resolve the problem and and even more important I have learned a new thing thanks to you. I have only a last question. With te command .save() I have noticed that save a new row in my total_income matrix. If I would like to overwrite the new value?? Ther'is some particolar commandto do it?

Comment: Good to here @FedericoDeMarco! If you have just created a record with `total_income.save()`, you can access the objects attributes with dot notation. For example, you can change total_jan by using `total_income.total_jan = 20.00`